# Basics instead of VectorListPlot

Tags: plotting, complex, vector

J.M. kindly proposed

```
ListVectorPlot[
 List /@ Table[
    {
     {x, k*Sin[x]}
     , {Re[k*x + I], -Im[k*x + I]}
     }
    , {k, {.01, .2, .4, .6, 1}}
    , {x, -1.57, 1.57, .1}
    ] // Evaluate
 , VectorStyle -> {Red, Brown, Blue, Pink, Purple}
 , VectorPoints -> All
 ]
```

The y component of the vectors plotted along these curves should just be the same 1  everywhere but they aren't.

**Is there any other way to portray a complex function's variation along a set of curves?**

**Oct 12 for example Can anyone please write  code  to equivalently
plot a series of short  lines from (x,k*sin[x]) to (x+.1*k*x,k*sin[x]+.1)
for {x, -1.57, 1.57, .1} and {k, {.01, .2, .4, .6, 1}} with according colors {Red, Brown, Blue, Pink, Purple}**

Comment: I know it messes up the coloring, but does removing `List /@ ` fix the scaling issue?

Comment: Yes that's where I started,but onmy real example Ineed the colur and no arrowheads to avoid overlaps.. I am wondering if there is a way to draw the (vector) line segments themselves from more primitive commands or  to automate this example for a string of k,                                        data1 = Table[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3,
    0.2}]; data2 = 
 Table[{-(1 + x - y^2), -1 - x^2 + y}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 
   0.2}];
ListVectorPlot[{data1, data2}, VectorPoints -> 8, 
 VectorStyle -> {Red, Blue}]